# System.IO.File.Copy Throws IOException

Tags: file, copy

I am trying to copy some files:

```
private void DoCopy() {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    string sFtpToReadFileFrom = "ftp://<user>:<pass>@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/";
    string sPathToWriteFileTo = Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data";

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
        string destFile = Path.Combine(sPathToWriteFileTo, fileName);
        byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData(sFtpToReadFileFrom + fileName); //shows correct bytes

        File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
```

The exact error is: The process cannot access the file 'C:\AppLauncher\AppLauncher\bin\Debug\App_Data\firstFile' because it is being used by another process.

I followed the 'MSDN How To' here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

If anyone finds any immediate red flags please do let me know.

Comment: What is first file supposed to be?

Comment: when I click on properties it just says file

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding your code... Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to download and copy files from my server on to my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I see it:

You want to download a file from an FTP server and write it to your local disk.
What you are doing is taking files in your source-directory as targets, which won't work at all. If the files already exist there, which they do if you can acquire their file names there. (hence the exception)

Here is what you must do

Connect to the FTP, acquire the files there (their bytes) and then create files on the disk.

```
private void DoCopy() {
    //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    //Acquire filenames from FTP-Server instead of local disk!

    string sFtpToReadFileFrom = "ftp://<user>:<pass>@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/";
    string sPathToWriteFileTo = Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data";

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s); //create file names based on FTP-server
        string destFile = Path.Combine(sPathToWriteFileTo, fileName);
        byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData(sFtpToReadFileFrom + fileName); //shows correct bytes

        //File.Copy(s, destFile, true); Rather use File.WriteAllBytes
        File.WriteAllBytes(destFile, fileData);
    }
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for an example of `File.WriteAllBytes`.

The acquiring of the filenames from FTP is not that straightforward, though. There is the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-class to support you.

Comment: Thanks. I need to update the files, they are all of the same name but different in file size (updated).

Comment: I just downloaded it, it shows the correct bytes, why will it not copy? :(

Comment: You can't update them using `File.Copy`, it will throw an System.IOException, when the target exists. Either delete the file before using `File.Copy` or the approach I presented.